# Linq error: not contain a definition for 'InsertOnSubmit'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have following code:

```
   public static bool Update(UserExtendedData data, byte[] image)
        {

            data.UserId = getUserId_new();

            IQueryable<UserExtendedData> entry = m_model.UserExtendedDataSet.Where(x => x.UserId == getUserId_new());
            UserExtendedData User = entry.Single();
            User.firstName = data.firstName;
            User.lastName = data.lastName;
            User.phoneNo = data.phoneNo;
            User.creditCardNo = data.creditCardNo;
            User.dateOfBirth = data.dateOfBirth;
            User.UserId = getUserId_new();

            if (image != null)
            {
                User.avatarArt = image;
            }
            m_model.UserExtendedDataSet.InsertOnSubmit(data);

            return true;
        }
```

I have include using System.Data.Linq; i'm using asp.net 4.5 on windows 7 (x64)
i also include:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

but i still got error:

```
does not contain a definition for 'InsertOnSubmit' and no extension method 'InsertOnSubmit' accepting a first argument of type ' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

But what is weird i got no problems with:

```
public static bool Insert(UserExtendedData data, byte[] image)
        {

            data.UserId = getUserId_new();

                if (image != null)
                    data.avatarArt = image;

                m_model.UserExtendedDataSet.Add(data) ;
                m_model.SaveChanges();
                return true;
        }
```

Do you have any ideas what could cause this problem ? I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using `Namespace:  System.Data.Linq`?

Comment: I only have: using System.Data.Linq; do i have using namespace ?

Comment: Please check Entity database should be dbml file not the dbmx file.

Comment: I do not understand fully what you mean, i using external db.

Comment: What is your Entity set file extension? If it is dbml then it will work else not

Comment: unfortunately it is dbmx, any idea how to circumvent this obstacle ?

Comment: `InsertOnSubmit` is a Linq-to-SQL method and not in the Entity Framework.so plz check your file name it should me .dbml.but if u r not getting any error with add that means it's not a dbml file and u r working with entity framework.

Comment: You can remove the whole line `m_model.UserExtendedDataSet.InsertOnSubmit(data);`. The context already tracks `User` and it is saved (updated, not inserted, as the method name suggests) when you call `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your `Entity set file extension`? If it is `dbml` then it will work else not in case of `dbmx`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333811/cant-find-insertonsubmit-method)

Comment: unfortunately it is dbmx, any idea how to circumvent this obstacle ?